# Cannot run android with react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I can't run project when install this lib.
I got error:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:generateGeneralDebugRFile'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-camera:generalDebugCompileClasspath'.
Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/chien/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/7a7f5a0af6ebd8eb94f7e5f7495e9d9684b4f543/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar.
> Java heap space
```

I tried install by docs:
missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' <-- add this line in android/app/build.gradle
Some time ago I was still able to run my project normally. But since yesterday, I can't run anymore
Can anyone help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is java heap space error, try increasing heap space by adding this to `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2g -XX\:MaxHeapSize\=4g
```